# Android login with Google and send mails

Tags: android

I am trying implement a google login screen into my app. it works pretty fine but i want store users data(Profile,Email,images) on server and mail them using mailchimp. this is possible? if yes how can i do that. any suggestion would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you can.
First if you accomplish the Google SignIn in your Class you must have the following lines...add the requestEmail()

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestEmail()  //add this line for Email
            .requestIdToken("yourIdToken")
            .build();
```

Now you can get information like name, email, url photo and others that you get from.

```
 private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    Log.d(TAG, "handleSignInResult:" + result.isSuccess());
    if (result.isSuccess()) {

        GoogleSignInAccount acct = result.getSignInAccount();
        acct.getDisplayName();
        acct.getEmail();
        acct.getPhotoUrl();
```

Now you have the information, store it and continue.
I hope it helps.

Comment: where i can store it? i need a server for that? if so how can i store in server sorry for too much questions. I am pretty new to android.

Comment: Well you can store that information on a database (SQLite maybe) if you have one, or use SharedPreferences here is the documentation about Saving Data https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html

Comment: Storing on shared preference then how can developer access it? I want all data if users